# Stored procedure does not run correctly when run by a SQL server job

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is going to be a long one, my apologizes...

My customer has SQL server 2008 R2. I have made a procedure for updating a certain table. The target is to update the rows for the same day as when the procedure is run at (but to be on the safe side it updates a few days more in to the past and in to the future. I have a SQL Agent job that is scheduled to run once per day at midnight to run my procedure.

If I run the procedure manually, it works. If I run the job manually (ie. left click on the job in the management studio and select "Start Job at Step") it works. However if the job runs by schedule, it does not work. According to the history the step with the procedure call has been run with no errors.

If I change the schedule in any way (for example change it to run 00:10), then the procedure works for that one day only, but the next day it does not. I have managed to replicate the problem manually exactly once by putting the procedure call inside a transaction - rollback and then viewing the result, but I have been unable to figure out why I was able to replicate the issue that one time. Also running the same thing just 5 minutes later was successful again.

I have logging that shows the parameters are exactly the same between a successful manual run and unsuccessful scheduled run. I have even tested the update part of the proc against the parameters from logging and it works that way. I have tried increasing the number of times the job is scheduled (up to once every hour) to no avail. I have also created a profiler trace to check how the procedure runs when called by the job, but I can't find any fault in it. No deadlocks either.

I think the problem is not that it's not updating anything, instead the problem looks to be that a null value is updated. However I can not understand this either as the logging shows a value for the variable (@DayWorkGroupNum) which holds the update value and still it makes no sense why the null value appears only with scheduling.

Finally the failed update seems last for 2 days and then sunddenly it updates everything that was missing (this is how the proc is designed, it finds the first missing day and then updates everything from that point on, but for some reason this only works every 3 days when running on schedule). For example right now the null values cover today and yesterday, but some time tomorrow when it runs, it will update all 3 days. This does however tell me it's not a user rights issue.

The problem part of the procedure is this:

```
UPDATE Dim_Shift SET WorkGroupNo = @DayWorkGroupNum
--SELECT * FROM Dim_Shift
WHERE date = DATEADD(DAY,@shiftIndex,@StartDate) 
and ShiftNo = 15
and WorkPhaseID in (
    SELECT WorkPhaseID FROM [Dim_WorkPhase]
    WHERE MillID = @pMillNo
)
```

That update is run under a loop that increases @shiftIndex by one (starting from 0) The loop is from current day -1 to current day + 2. The faulty update concerns ONLY @shiftIndex 1 or 0 and 1.

As I mentioned before, I have logging included that shows me the that  @DayWorkGroupNum, @shiftIndex, @StartDate are correct. @pMillNo is a parameter and is always 13. This is also the part that I tested using the parameters I get from logging and if I disable the update part and enable the select part then the select shows exactly the result set that should be updated.

I also have a try catch for the entire procedure and set to log errors separately, but no errors have been logged.

For example parameters for the current day update statement are:

@shiftIndex = 1 (0 is yesterday), @DayWorkGroupNum = 1, @StartDate = 2019-05-01 (is always todays date - 1 day)

Few example rows from the table BEFORE update

```
+-------------+------------+---------+-------------+
| WorkPhaseID |    Date    | ShiftNo | WorkGroupNo |
+-------------+------------+---------+-------------+
|         206 | 2019-05-02 |      15 | NULL        |
|         207 | 2019-05-02 |      15 | NULL        |
|         208 | 2019-05-02 |      15 | NULL        |
|         209 | 2019-05-02 |      15 | NULL        |
+-------------+------------+---------+-------------+
```

and after update it should look like this:

```
+-------------+------------+---------+-------------+
| WorkPhaseID |    Date    | ShiftNo | WorkGroupNo |
+-------------+------------+---------+-------------+
|         206 | 2019-05-02 |      15 |           1 |
|         207 | 2019-05-02 |      15 |           1 |
|         208 | 2019-05-02 |      15 |           1 |
|         209 | 2019-05-02 |      15 |           1 |
+-------------+------------+---------+-------------+
```

but instead WorkGroupNo remains NULL. Just recently I noticed that if there is any old data on the workGroupNo, then the proc converts it to NULL, but this applies only for the current day and sometimes the day before.

--EDIT--
I failed to explain above that the database in question is very old and has quite a lot of traffic. With that in mind, I have discovered that problem is table specific: I added a new step to the job which calls a new procedure, which writes to a brand new table I made myself and that works just fine.

Comment: Have you looked in SQL Logs to see what error was thrown? Or that it was run at all? In SSMS, go to Management > SQL server Logs and check the logfile for when it was due to run. are you sure that the SQL Agent service is running?

Comment: Nothing in the logs about my proc. And yes the Agent is running as it has a lot of other tasks as well that work just fine. I also know the proc does run because of the logs I write from within the code.

Comment: Can you log what DayWordGroupNum, shiftIndex, and StartDate are set to just before they're used in the update? It could be that one of them is not what you expect; for example if DayWorkGroupNum is null then the update may well be working correctly and your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I do that already, here is a log extract from today: 
Generating StartDate = 2019-05-02;
shiftIndex = 0, DayWorkGroupNum = 1;
shiftIndex = 1, DayWorkGroupNum = 2;
... up to shiftIndex 3, but shiftIndex = 1 is for todays date

Comment: So shiftIndex is getting calculated incorrectly?

Comment: Your last edit suggests that there is/are some other processes/applications/scheduled jobs that update the same old table that your procedure is updating and their updates interfere with yours. Something like "whoever acts last wins and overwrites what was written before it". Try to figure out who else is updating that table.

Comment: @simonatrcl Sorry, I think I explained that a bit poorly. But the shiftindex is correct, it should be 0 for yesterday, 1 for today, 2 for tomorrow and 3 for the day after tomorrow. Ergo the idea is to do DATEADD to the startdate using shiftindex as a day.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I am starting to lean on that as well. I was able to finally replicate the problem manually by putting the procedure call inside a rollback transaction and viewing the results. Running it multiple times the problem seems to occur only when the query takes longer than normal to run. Still the consistency of the failed runs using scheduling is still baffling. No matter how I change the actual time and frequency to schedule the query it always succeeds on the first run and then it goes back to the pattern of succeeding every 3 days.